# R: how to group almost similar words

Tags: r

I have a DNA sequence words of 8 letters each. There are about 50,000 words, for sample "AAAAAAAA" "TTTTTTTT" "AAAAACGC" "AAAACCTG" so on. Now I want to group all words in such a order that all the words of 6 similar letters group together. Please some one help me out.
 I need to cluster all the 2 substitution words into one cluster and more than 2 substitution words into another cluster. For example "AAAAACCA" can fall in both " AAAAAAAA" and "AAAACCCA" .But, "AAAAACCA" should belongs to cluster "AAAACCCA" because it is 1 substitution away compare to "AAAAAAAA". Suppose "AAAAAAAG" can belong to either "AAAAAAAA" or "AAAAAAAC" but not both. I hope you get my point, if you have any further clarification please comment me. Thank you.

```
    words <- sample[1:25]
> group <- lapply(words, function(x)list(x,words[agrep(x, words,max.distance=list(all=2, insertions=0, deletions=0, substitutions=2))]))
> group
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "AAAAAAAA"

[[1]][[2]]
 [1] "AAAAAAAA" "AAAAAAAC" "AAAAAAAG" "AAAAAAAT" "AAAAAACA" "AAAAAACC" "AAAAAACG" "AAAAAACT"
 [9] "AAAAAAGA" "AAAAAAGC" "AAAAAAGG" "AAAAAAGT" "AAAAAATA" "AAAAAATC" "AAAAAATG" "AAAAAATT"
[17] "AAAAACAA" "AAAAACAC" "AAAAACAG" "AAAAACAT" "AAAAACCA" "AAAAACGA"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "AAAAAAAC"

[[2]][[2]]
 [1] "AAAAAAAA" "AAAAAAAC" "AAAAAAAG" "AAAAAAAT" "AAAAAACA" "AAAAAACC" "AAAAAACG" "AAAAAACT"
 [9] "AAAAAAGA" "AAAAAAGC" "AAAAAAGG" "AAAAAAGT" "AAAAAATA" "AAAAAATC" "AAAAAATG" "AAAAAATT"
[17] "AAAAACAA" "AAAAACAC" "AAAAACAG" "AAAAACAT" "AAAAACCC"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "AAAAAAAG"

[[3]][[2]]
 [1] "AAAAAAAA" "AAAAAAAC" "AAAAAAAG" "AAAAAAAT" "AAAAAACA" "AAAAAACC" "AAAAAACG" "AAAAAACT"
 [9] "AAAAAAGA" "AAAAAAGC" "AAAAAAGG" "AAAAAAGT" "AAAAAATA" "AAAAAATC" "AAAAAATG" "AAAAAATT"
[17] "AAAAACAA" "AAAAACAC" "AAAAACAG" "AAAAACAT" "AAAAACCG"
```

how to reduce the redundency in my output.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i have used adist function, matchPattern function but nothing worked.

Comment: Please show this efforts in your post.

Comment: similar<- rep(0,50000) # similar array
dissimilar<- rep(0,50000) # dissimilar array
for(i in 1:50000){
  if(i <= i){
    similar[i] <- words[i] # words is the array of DNA words
  }
  else
  for(j in i+1:50000){
    
    if(adist(words[i],words[j]) < 3){
     similar[j]<- words[j]
    }
    else
    disimilar[j] <- words[j]
  }
}

Comment: **Inside** your post!

Comment: you could try the `stringdist` package for string distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your `adist` call, you could do:

```
words <- c("AAAAAAAA", "TTTTTTTT", "AAAAAAGC", "AAAACCAA")
lapply(words, function(x) words[adist(x, words) < 3])
```

You could also try this using `agrep`, though it's likely to be much slower:

```
words <- c("AAAAAAAA", "TTTTTTTT", "AAAAAAGC", "AAAACCAA")
d<-lapply(words, 
   function(x) list(match.word=x, six.letter.grp = words[agrep(x, words, 
   max.distance=list(all=2, insertions=0, deletions=0, substitutions=2))]))
```

This outputs the following list that shows the word you're matching against, and all the words it matches including the word itself, but you could tweak the output depending on what exactly you want:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$match.word
[1] "AAAAAAAA"

[[1]]$six.letter.grp
[1] "AAAAAAAA" "AAAAAAGC" "AAAACCAA"


[[2]]
[[2]]$match.word
[1] "TTTTTTTT"

[[2]]$six.letter.grp
[1] "TTTTTTTT"


[[3]]
[[3]]$match.word
[1] "AAAAAAGC"

[[3]]$six.letter.grp
[1] "AAAAAAAA" "AAAAAAGC"


[[4]]
[[4]]$match.word
[1] "AAAACCAA"

[[4]]$six.letter.grp
[1] "AAAAAAAA" "AAAACCAA"
```

For a more compact list structure, you could try:

```
d <- lapply(words, function(x) words[agrep(x, words,
         max.distance=list(all=2, insertions=0, deletions=0, substitutions=2))])
names(d) <- words
d
#$AAAAAAAA
#[1] "AAAAAAAA" "AAAAAAGC" "AAAACCAA"
#
#$TTTTTTTT
#[1] "TTTTTTTT"
# 
#$AAAAAAGC
#[1] "AAAAAAAA" "AAAAAAGC"
#
#$AAAACCAA
#[1] "AAAAAAAA" "AAAACCAA"
```

Comment: how can I avoid redundency in the output?

Comment: @VikasBanka There are a number of things you can do depending on what exactly you are looking for.  You did not provide a minimal reproducible example or give any desired output, but you should always do that when asking a question on Stack Overflow.  What redundancy do you want to avoid?  Can you add your desired output to your question for a small sample dataset, such as the `words` data I used?

Comment: hey i have just edited my question you can see a part my output, you can see redundency in my out put.

Comment: @VikasBanka I see the output you get from using my answer, but *I don't see your desired output*.  You need to define what you want to happen to words that match more than one word.  Think about this problem: `"AAAAACCA"` is 2 substitutions from `"AAAAAAAA"` and from `"AAAACCCA"` which are 3 substitutions from each other.  Which group should `"AAAAACCA"` belong to?  Does this make sense?  The issue here is that you need to define your question and desired output more explicitly so that people know exactly what you want.

Comment: the Base idea is , I need to cluster all the 2 substitution words into one cluster and more than 2 substitution words into another cluster. so "AAAAACCA" can fall in both " AAAAAAAA" and "AAAACCCA" .But, "AAAAACCA" should belongs to cluster "AAAACCCA" because it is 1substitution away compare to "AAAAAAAA". Suppose "AAAAAAAG" can belong to either "AAAAAAAA" or "AAAAAAAC" but not both. I hope you get my point, if you have any further clarification please comment me. Thank you.